# Python double-ended queue issue

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a program that runs constantly unless the user presses q to end it. The program asks the user for a number and puts the number in a queue, then it prints the queue with the new element at the end. If the number is with 01,02 then it will be added at the left hand side without the 0 at the beginning, otherwise at the right hand side. The user can remove an item from the end of the queue by typing r.

I got the starting point where it asks the user and goes until 'q' is pressed.

```
while True:
    if input("\n\n\nType  a number to add it to the queue or q to exit: ") == 'q':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate out the `input` call from the logic that depends on the value it returns. Instead, assign the value to a variable that you can examine several times:

```
while True:
    val = input(...)
    if val == 'q':
       break

    if val.startswith('0'):
       ...
    else:
       ...
```

Comment: if val.startswitch('0') how does it add at the beginning? also wouldn't take all the numbers that contain 0, eg 10 and not only the ones beginning with 0, eg 01?

Comment: 'code'  import collections
queue = list()
status = ''
instructions = "\ninteger to add or q to exit: "

while True:

    response = input(status + instructions)
    response = response.lower()  
    if response == 'q':
        break
    if response == 'r':     #remove from right
        queue.pop()
    if response =='0r':     #removefrom left
        queue.popleft()
    try:
        number = int(response)  
    except ValueError:
        status = "ignore: " + response
        continue

    queue.append(response)
    status = "queue = " + str(queue)
 'code'

Comment: missing the part where r removes from end of the queue and 0r from beginning of the queue. Please some help.